# PHPStorm+WSL+XDebug - не заводится отладка

Tags: phpstorm, magento, xdebug, wsl2

Всем добрый день.
Прошу помощи по настройке Xdebug
Что имеется:

- phpstorm 2023.1
- wsl 2 Ubuntu 22.04.2
- php 7.4
- xdebug 3.1.6
- magento 2.4.5
- Xdebug helper for Chrome

/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug,develop
xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
;cat /etc/resolv.conf ???
;xdebug.client_host=
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

/etc/hosts

`127.0.0.1 magetest.web`

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

`127.0.0.1 magetest.web`

Phpstorm...Settings...PHP...

- ...CLI interpreter - настроено на WSL, версия Xdebug отображается
- ...Servers: Host=magetest.web, Port=80, Debugger=Xdebug
  Mapping:
  //wsl$/Ubuntu/home/admin/projects/magetest.web    /home/admin/projects/magetest.web
- ...Debug: Debug ports=9000,9003
- ...Debug...DBGp proxy: IDE key=PHPSTORM;Host=127.0.0.1;Port=9000
- Run...Edit configuration...PHP Remote Debug, **Rdebug**
  Server=magetest.web
  IDE key=PHPSTORM

Start listening (трубка) включил
Xdebug helper установлен в Debug

При запуске **Rdebug**  в окне Debug указано

> Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'

уже ставил для нужной станицы в адресе "?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM"
все равно отладка не заводится....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу
в **/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini**
в поле
**xdebug.client_host**
указываем **ip**, который находится в **/etc/resolv.conf**

PowerShell этот же **ip** видим при выводе команды **ipconfig**, в блоке WSL

В обоих **hosts** этот **ip** у меня указан как **winhost**

А теперь самое важное....
В настройках PHPStorm, CLI iterpreter, справа от поля **PHP executable** есть кнопочка с двумя стрелочками в виде окружности [image: -]. Вот эту кнопку нужно **ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО** нажимать при любом изменении конфигов со стороны Ubuntu.